# Which to use Jquery or Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my project  i have to create an Accordion.which is better to use Jquery or Ajax

Comment: I think first you have to learn what is the difference between [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and  [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery). Basically Ajax is some kind of technique whereas jQuery is a JavaScript framework that makes it easier to use Ajax (among other things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AJAX is for server-side requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), to get or send new data for your page (without a full page reload), it's an alltogether different concept.

For the accordion, I think you're looking for the [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), though there are many options out there.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bit like asking "What should I use to get to work today? A car or an accelerator pedal?"

AJAX is a general term that refers to the techniques that make use of client-side scripting (e.g. JavaScript) to communicate with the server between page-loads.

jQuery is a framework (a set of libraries and tools) that make writing JavaScript simpler and easier. It includes facilities for using AJAX.

Comment: Watch out @Will, @sundowatch might tell you that jQuery is a library if you're not careful.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, [Apples, Hammers, or music?  how to decide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495695/dhtml-library-for-handling-pictures-and-videos-using-ajax/2548686#2548686)

Comment: Hammers, then you can make every problem a nail.

Comment: Apples, hammers and music all suck! You want horses!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX, or Asynchronous Javascript and XML, is an umbrella term for the technologies and methodologies involved in loading data from the server without a page request.

jQuery is a Javascript library.

Javascript is a client side scripting language.

As @Nick said, the jQuery UI accordion plugin is a good choice for the accordion.