# Difference between updating static page text with jquery versus AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I haven't quite learned AJAX yet, but what I have read is that it is useful for updating a small part of a page. Is this only for when you need access to a server?

I need to remove text from a page and add more different text, what is difference between implementing this through an onclick() event in jquery (hiding text, adding text to replace, and having another function to replace the original text). I have no need for a database because the information is static.

Should I implement ajax for this or is the jquery solution sufficient? Will the jquery solution reload the entire page?

Edit: My question is different because I have a more specific example and really asking which is best practice, not a vague statement, "which one to use" with little context. I have to remove two `<h2>` tags and four `<p>` tags on a single page text website. I want to replace them with a single header and paragraph. detail Am I doing this right? I'm new to this site.

Comment: Jquery is a JavaScript library that makes it easier to manipulate DOM, animate elements, and other JavaScript functions. Ajax is a means of making JavaScript calls to the server or other servers asynchronously or synchronisouly behind the scenes. The two are not exclusive as jquery has it own implementation of Ajax that makes it easier to make Ajax calls. It depends on what you want to do. If you want to just update a specific element without marking a call to retrieve data from anywhere then pure JavaScript or jquery can get it done.

Comment: if you need to access a file use ajax otherwise you can change the dom using event listeners. and neither ajax nor eventlisteners will reload the page.

Comment: This is an innocent question so I'm not going to downvote it, but the truth is that all answers will be quoting manuals and/or merely offering examples.  Examples abound on the web, please continue researching and experimenting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which to use Jquery or Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826416/which-to-use-jquery-or-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand the concept. `AJAX` is required where you want to `fetch or post some data from or to server` by maintaining the current state of the page.

But in case you want some thing like:

```
Change the color of the selected row of a table.
Change the text of a div when clicked.
Hide/Show some content etc
```

you don't need `AJAX` always. This can be maintained on client side using `JS` or `Jquery`.